# What's the difference between a monostatic and a colocated radar?

Tags: radar

I have heard the two terms thrown around in a somewhat interchangeable manner it seems. Are there any major differences? I haven't gathered that they have a different meaning, but I don't understand why there would be two different words if that were the case, as it seems authors choose one over the other somewhat randomly.

Comment: I don't know, but just from the normal meaning of the words, it seems like a bistatic radar could be called "collocated" if the receive module and transmit module were right next to each other. "Monostatic" makes it sound like there is actually only one module that performs both transmit and receive. Or maybe even one antenna.

Answer (score 1):

They seem to be synonymous: "Monostatic radar is the term given to a radar in which the transmitter and receiver are collocated. This is the conventional configuration for a radar, but the term is used to distinguish it from a bistatic radar or multistatic radar." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monostatic_radar)